# Execvp Memory Error

Tags: c, memory-leaks

So I have a c program that is takes in an input of commands but occasionally I seem to be getting some sort of memory error.

How I read input:

```
static void parseLine(char* commandLine, Sequence* sequences, int* seqSize) {
   char copyLine[MAX_LENGTH];
   char* token;

   strcpy(copyLine, commandLine);

   token = strtok(copyLine, DELIM);

   while (token != NULL) { /* updates args here */


   }
}
```

I print out my Sequence arguments before calling the function above and all seems to be good. Using Valgrind I get the following (in execute):

```
Invalid read of size 1
```

The command I am calling is

```
cat aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/test
```

However when my program fails it prints out:

```
cat: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaD: No such file or directory
```

This seems to be becoming overwritten. Can someone explain why?

Comment: What’s `MAX_LENGTH`?

Comment: @Ryan It's 1025

Comment: The fact that people are asking you fundamental details necessary to get the code working on their system indicates that you've not provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and it's possible that the error lies elsewhere. There are four words in MCVE: 1/ minimal 2/ complete 3/ verifiable 4/ example; your code must meet all four criteria, and at the moment it's not *verifiable* because the code you've given us doesn't produce *memory errors*; it produces *compiler errors* due to being *incomplete*.

Comment: In spite of being *incomplete*, your code includes logic which I'd suggest can't possibly be related to your *memory errors*, so your code isn't minimal, complete or verifiable; it's just an example, and one we can't do anything with, except perhaps suggest that you read [the first sentence of this here `execvp` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) because that's a common problem which you might have missed in a quest to *guess as much as possible and read as little as possible*.

Comment: @Sebivor Thanks, but I actually did research execvp. However, this was on the man pages. I'm sorry if I appeared to guess as much as possible but I believe I did do my research. As I mentioned above, my code was only failing in rare cases.

Comment: All good, Zach. Don't take it personally, I'm not attacking people but behaviours when I write rants like this. These rants are getting longer because it's an ongoing issue, that people don't read *something or other* and hence end up writing questions about code which doesn't compile while claiming it does compile (and outputs something)... but I guess it is to be expected so I probably should just roll with it. I wonder if StackOverflow needs to evolve towards encouraging people to just generally *read more than they write*. Having said that, it's not in SOs best interests to do that, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `parseLine` you copy the arguments into a local variable which you then pass to `strtok`:

```
   char copyLine[MAX_LENGTH];
   ...
   strcpy(copyLine, commandLine);

   token = strtok(copyLine, DELIM);
```

You then store the resulting pointers in `args`, which you then use to initialize your structures.

Note that `strtok` returns pointers to the beginning of each token within the supplied buffer, so within the local variable `copyLine`. Local variables can only be referenced inside the function where they are declared, if you later refer to those pointers after returning from the function, the result is undefined.

You are making a copy inside `makeSequence`, but you are copying the array of pointers, not the strings that the pointers are pointing to!

To avoid this, either allocate `copyLine` on the heap (and free it later) or pass it in from outside.